# Jquery object compare problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to compare two Jquery object?

```
$('<p></p>')[0] === $('<p></p>')[0]
false

$('<p></p>') == $('<p></p>')
false

$('<p></p>').get() == $('<p></p>').get()
false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following returns `true`

```
$('<p></p>').html() == $('<p></p>').html();
```

Is that what you need?

**Edit:** The old jQuery group^ [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/jquery-en/compre$20jquery$20objects/jquery-en/AC11Qxht2qY/NV5hbYNRyOcJ) on this suggests comparing the child nodes in plain JavaScript since each jQuery object is an array of references to DOM objects. This function was also the accepted answer on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176962/jquery-object-equality/3177083#3177083).

^Tried the new jQuery forum but it has not imported the discussion correctly.

Comment: Ah yes sorry, you want to compare objects. They will be different objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<p>') // it creates a new dom element. 
         //Equivalent to document.createElement('p')
```

so the two

```
$('<p></p>')[0] and $('<p></p>')[0]
```

are in fact two distinct DOM elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<p></p>')[0].outerHTML === $('<p></p>')[0].outerHTML;   // true
$('<p>hi</p>')[0].outerHTML === $('<p></p>')[0].outerHTML; // false
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a stupid solution ... anyone got better one?

`$.md5($('<p></p>').get()[0].toString()) ==$.md5($('<p></p>').get()[0].toString())`

Comment: Why the `md5()`? If the md5 hashes are equal, so are the two `.toString()` values (probably).