# how do I write a `is_a_last_of_b(a, b)` to check whether `a` is the last child of `b`

Tags: jquery

```
a = $('div:first');
b = $('div');
```

`b` may contain multiple DOM elements.

But `a` only contains 1 element.

How do I know if `a` is the last element of `b`?

I tried `a == $('div:last')`,but it's wrong after my test.

And if `a` is an element of `b`, how do I get the sibling of `a` within `b`?

**Clarify**

the problem is how I can write a `is_a_last_of_b(a, b)` to check whether `a` is the last child of `b`.

And if `a` is a direct child of `b`,how to write `next_sibling(a)` to return the next sibling of `a`(only one)?

Comment: Your question is really unclear. What is "last element of `b`"? And which sibling are you referring to?

Comment: Could you perhaps edit in some example HTML?

Comment: Assuming "element of" means "child of" (your question is still confusing), `div:first` can **never** be a child of another `div` since `div:first` would select the very first, outermost `div` in the document.

Comment: @BoltClock,that's just an example ,the problem is how I can write a `is_a_last_of_b(a, b)`.

Comment: Tried to fix your title, edit if this is not correct. Anything is better than "Question about jQuery" though, can't get much more vague than that. I don't get `is_a_last`, how many **last** elements do you expect?

Comment: @bitsMix,it has nothing to do with html

Comment: @Wesley Murch ,I know how to select the last ,just put `:last` in the selector.

Answer (score 1):

Can try this

```
var elements = $("div");
var lastElement = elements.filter(":last");
var firstElement = elements.filter(":first");
```

For sibling check this out [jquery siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Comment: This is not what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need [last-selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) and [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)?

Comment: How do you get the next **1** sibling of `a`?I only want to get one,not all.

Comment: @new_perl: The last child cannot possibly have a next sibling.

Comment: Yes, in that case,should match nothing.But if not the last,should return the next sibling.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to compare jquery objects, you can look at some other questions on SO like this one: [jQuery object equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176962/jquery-object-equality)

Essentially, in your case where you only want to check for one item you could do this:

```
var a = $("div:first"),
    b = $("div");

if (b[b.length - 1] === a[0]) {}

// or

if (b.last()[0] = a[0]) {}
```

Then, to get the next sibling of an element:

```
b = b.next();
```