# How do I use jquery in comparing the two selectors?

Tags: jquery

I have to compare two selectors and I was wondering why does this return false in firebug...and how do I compare two selectors

```
$('.product-info:last') == $('.product-info:last')
```

this is what I have to do

```
    var previous = $('.product-info:visible');
    if(previous == $('.product-info:last')){
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: are you trying to compare the selector? the jquery object it returns?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery object equality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176962/jquery-object-equality)

Comment: comparing if its the same selector

Comment: Keep in mind that `$("#text")` is a jQuery object.  `==` when comparing two objects only tests to see if they are the exact same object, not that they have the same contents.  That's why your method of comparing doesn't work since each object in this `$('.product-info:last') == $('.product-info:last')` is different so they are never `==`.  @Royi has a decent work-around.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason `$('.product-info:last') !== $('.product-info:last')` is because jQuery create a new object for each one of those, they are not the same jQuery object.

Use [is](http://api.jquery.com/is/) instead to check if elements are the same.

```
previous.is('.product-info:last')
```

Comment: Caution: my read of [jquery is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) is that it doesn't test if two selectors are **identical**, merely that they **overlap**.  So for example this would work too:  `previous.is(':last')`

Answer (score 5):

try :

```
$('.product-info:last').get(0) == $('.product-info:last').get(0)
```

Comment: I think ".get(0)" would be better, as that'd get you the DOM node and not a jQuery object.

Comment: I always confusing between those two

Comment: Works only if the selector contains exactly one DOM element. If the selector selects more than one element, this test will be incomplete.

Comment: @mblase75 `If the selector selects more than one` **but it doesnt** ... first and last are returning 1.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes, of course; I was obviously describing the problem with the *general* solution. Your approach only works with this specific selector, not with all possible selectors.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
var previous = $('.product-info:visible');
if (previous.is('.product-info:last')) {
    return false;
}
```