# obj == JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) is false

Tags: javascript, json, object

I was looking at the JavaScript console in Chrome and noticed something strange, even though they appear the same, `obj` and `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` are not the same. Why is that?

```
var obj = {test:'this is a test', another: {omg:'ay dios mio', check:true}};
console.log(obj, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)));
console.log(obj == JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)));
```

They look identical but return false when you check equality. Why is that?

Comment: Not *really* a duplicate, but the answer there answers your question too.

Comment: If you convert both to strings `JSON.stringify()` then you'll see their values are equal.

Comment: [MDN: Equality operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality_operators) `[...]If both operands are objects, then JavaScript compares internal references which are equal when operands refer to the same object in memory.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They're not equal for the same reason this returns false:

```
({omg:'ay dios mio', check:true}) == ({omg:'ay dios mio', check:true})
```

You're not comparing the values inside the object, but the object references. They'll be different.

Answer (score 5):

The objects are testing for REFERENCES.

While primitives are testing for VALUE.

Answer (score 5):

Because the `obj` does not reference the parsed object in memory. So these are 2 different declarations. If you do this:

```
var a = [ 10 ],
    b = [ 10 ];
```

Then there are 2 instances of arrays with the same values, but that doesn't make them the same array. So `a != b`, even though `10 == 10`. You can increase the value of `a[0]` to 15, but that doesn't change the value of `b[0]` to 15.

Therefore, if you want to compare objects, you have to loop through them and check if the values of the objects are the same.

A function to compare (borrowed from [jQuery object equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176962/jquery-object-equality) )

```
$.fn.equals = function(compareTo) {
  if (!compareTo || this.length != compareTo.length) {
    return false;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
    if (this[i] !== compareTo[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};
```

Comment: But the way they reference are the same, I could have made it objects with just 1 property. That's true.

Comment: Yes (because arrays are objects). It's just, introducing further non-relevant factors tends to obscure the explanation...