# Why does `$(document) === $(document)` returns false in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, operators, comparison-operators

I tried `$(document) === $(document)` but found the result is `false`..

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: the same reason `{} === {}` returns false, no two objects will ever equal each other unless they are the exact same object, ie `a = b = {}; a===b`

Comment: Please explain the reason for reopening.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you use jQuery you get a JS object back. This object is totally different every time you use the jQuery selector.

To understand this better, I played in the console with some arrays:

```
a = [1, 2]
[1,2]
b = [1, 2]
[1,2]
a == b
false
a === b
false
```

When using jQuery it's just like using objects, **because you don't get a DOM element in response** (maybe that why you got confused)

**How Can You Do It?**

If you do want to compare 2 jQuery objects you could use the [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) jQuery method:

```
$(document).is($(document))
true
```

Answer (score 19):

Because on top of jQuery, every call (`$()` or `jQuery()`) to it returns new instance:

```
return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
```

So all jQuery instances (Even for same selectors) are always different (E.g. `$("#id") === $("#id")//false`)

You can check source code (Line 78) of [jQuery 2.1.0](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js)

But if you put it to variable, you can achieve an equality:

```
var d, d_copy;

d = $(document);

d_copy = d;

d_copy === d;  //true
```

Answer (score 7):

**[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176962/jquery-object-equality)**

You can check equality of two object using **[is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)** function like

```
alert($(document).is($(document)));  // return true
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/canud8y5/)**

Answer (score 5):

Each time you select the `document` element using jQuery, you are given a new selection of that element encapsulated in a jQuery object.

Thus, the first call to `$(document)` selects the `document` element in the DOM and gives you a new instance of a jQuery object which holds that selection. The second selection hands you yet another instance of a jQuery object encapsulating the same `document` element. While these jQuery objects do indeed have identical data members, they are two distinct objects encapsulating the `document` DOM element.