# simple jquery comparison doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I want to add an active class to a nav element, but i don't get it working.
My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('a[href="<?php echo RoutingClass::getView(); ?>"]') == $('a[href="home"]')) {
        $('a[href="home"]').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

and when its parsed in the browser, it looks like this (on the homepage):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('a[href="home"]') == $('a[href="home"]')) {
        $('a[href="home"]').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

when i leave out the if comparison, it just adds the active class, but in it, it doesnt.

Comment: I think you want to be checking strings, ie `"home" == "<?php echo RoutingClass::getView(); ?>"`

Comment: That looks so terribly hackish, you just don't echo PHP in JS..

Comment: That worked, thanks james

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if that jQuery element you select has the home href like that:

```
$('a[href="home"]').attr("href") == "home"
```

Your code will work like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if ( $('a[href="home"]').attr("href") == "home" ) {
    $('a[href="home"]').addClass('active');
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

See [jQuery object equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176962/jquery-object-equality) for a discussion about jquery equality.

My suggestion for your code is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (<?php echo RoutingClass::getView()=='home'?'1':'0' ?>)) {
        $('a[href="home"]').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing 2 DOM elements.

Lets use an IDfor each of anchor tags, I've called them a1 and a2 :

```
$('a#a1').attr('href') == $('a#a2').attr('href')
```