# jQuery referencing created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm rather confused, what is the difference between elementsWrapper1 and elementsWrapper2? Shouldn't the last log expression evaluate as true?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

JS (jQuery):

```
var container = $('.container');

var elementsWrapper1 = $('<div>', {
    class : 'elements-wrapper'
});

container.children().wrapAll(elementsWrapper1);

var elementsWrapper2 = $('.elements-wrapper');

console.log(elementsWrapper1);
console.log(elementsWrapper2);

//Returns False, but why?
console.log(elementsWrapper1 === elementsWrapper2)
```

Thanks

Comment: `elementwrapper1` gets every `DIV` with that class `elementwrapper2` grabs every element with that class

Comment: The 2 objects are not equal since their underlying html is different. https://jsfiddle.net/7w5k5vxo/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `$()`, either to create an object (as you did with `elementsWrapper1`) or perform a selection (as with `elementsWrapper2`), it creates a new jQuery object. Even if two jQuery objects refer to the same collection of DOM elements, they're not the same Javascript object, so `===` will consider them non-equal.

If you want to test whether two jQuery objects are equivalent, you can use the `.is()` method.

```
console.log(elementsWrapper1.is(elementsWrapper2));
```

See [jQuery object equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176962/jquery-object-equality)