# How to know if two jquery objects are pointing to the same element

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below alerts `false`

```
var a = $('html'); 
var b = $('html'); 
alert(a==b);
```

Is there a way to know if two variables are pointing to the same element?

Comment: Two separate jQuery instances will never be equal. You could compare `a[0] == b[0]`, but in general you'd want to check the length of each jQuery instance and then the list of elements one by one.

Comment: Check [jQuery object equality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176962/jquery-object-equality)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the normal equality operators (ie. `==` and `===`) doesn't work for objects. However, you can use the `is()` method to compare two jQuery objects, like this:

```js
var $a = $('html'); 
var $b = $('html'); 

if ($a.is($b)) {
  console.log('same')
} else {
  console.log('not the same');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew `.is` and have used it a lot like `is(':checked')`. but didn't know it can be used like this.

Comment: Note that `is()` checks if *at least one of* the elements in the first collection ***is in*** the second collection, the two collections can be completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Use the javascript `isSameNode()` method. [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_issamenode.asp)

```
var a = $('html'); 
var b = $('html'); 
alert(a[0].isSameNode(b[0]));
```

The [0] indexer of a jquery object returns the native DOM object