# Object equality in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I compare if two objects are equal in jQuery.

```
var a = { id:"1", name:"name"};
var b = { id:"1"};
b.name = "name";
```

How can I check for equality between a and b ? Is there a method similiar to `.equals()` in JAVA which can be overridden ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176962/jquery-object-equality

Comment: Take a look at this stackoverflow [http://stackoverflow.com/a/42310136/7599559](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42310136/7599559)