# When nodeType() used in object behaves different in jQuery versions '1.11.2' and '3.1.1'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am eager to know why the jQuery versions '1.11.2' and '3.1.1' behaves in two different ways while using nodeType() function in jQuery object.

To illustrate this, I have two fiddle links for these two versions.

jquery-1.11.2
 https://jsfiddle.net/38z9m9j9/9/

jquery-3.1.1
 https://jsfiddle.net/38z9m9j9/8/

And in this, I have an condition that,

```
this.options.data == data.colors[0];
```

This gets equal only in version '1.11.2' on using '**nodeType()**' function for object 'this.options.data.colors[0]' where as not working in '3.1.1'. So, how does the 'nodeType()' works here in '1.11.2'?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe start here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176962/jquery-object-equality

Answer (score 4):

Cause of the problem in the difference in implementation of the function `isPlainObject` in these two versions of jQuery.

> The current isPlainObject in 1.4 tests .nodeType because IE makes dom nodes look like objects. This has the side effect that $.isPlainObject({ nodeType: ... }); will return false when it should return true. (From [jQuery Forum](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/improvement-to-isplainobject))

**Use jQuery 1.11.2**

```js
var data = {
  colors: {
    id: 1,
    color: "red",
    nodeType: function () {},
  }
};

function logPlain (value, log) {
 value && value.color == "red" && $('#plain').text(log);
}

//from release of jQuery UI-1.12.1
$.widget.extend = function( target ) {
 var widgetSlice = Array.prototype.slice;
  var input = widgetSlice.call( arguments, 1 );
 var inputIndex = 0;
 var inputLength = input.length;
 var key;
 var value;

 for ( ; inputIndex < inputLength; inputIndex++ ) {
  for ( key in input[ inputIndex ] ) {
   value = input[ inputIndex ][ key ];
   if ( input[ inputIndex ].hasOwnProperty( key ) && value !== undefined ) {

    // Clone objects
    if ( $.isPlainObject( value ) ) {
          logPlain(value, 'true');
     target[ key ] = $.isPlainObject( target[ key ] ) ?
      $.widget.extend( {}, target[ key ], value ) :

      // Don't extend strings, arrays, etc. with objects
      $.widget.extend( {}, value );

    // Copy everything else by reference
    } else {
          logPlain(value, 'false');
     target[ key ] = value;
    }
   }
  }
 }
 return target;
};

$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.widget2", {
    options: {
      data: null
    },
    _create: function() {
      var isDataEqual = this.options.data == data.colors;
      $('#equal').text(isDataEqual ? "true" : "false");
    },
  });

  $("#my-widget1").widget2({
    data: data.colors
  });

});
```

```css
#equal, #plain {
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.31);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="my-widget1">Testing 'nodeType' in jQuery version-1.11.2</div>
  <div>isPlainObject: <span id="plain"></div>
  <div>isDataEqual: <span id="equal"></span></div>
</div>
```

**Use jQuery 3.1.1:**

```js
var data = {
  colors: {
    id: 1,
    color: "red",
    nodeType: function () {},
  }
};

function logPlain (value, log) {
 value && value.color == "red" && $('#plain').text(log);
}

//from release of jQuery UI-1.12.1
$.widget.extend = function( target ) {
 var widgetSlice = Array.prototype.slice;
  var input = widgetSlice.call( arguments, 1 );
 var inputIndex = 0;
 var inputLength = input.length;
 var key;
 var value;

 for ( ; inputIndex < inputLength; inputIndex++ ) {
  for ( key in input[ inputIndex ] ) {
   value = input[ inputIndex ][ key ];
   if ( input[ inputIndex ].hasOwnProperty( key ) && value !== undefined ) {

    // Clone objects
    if ( $.isPlainObject( value ) ) {
          logPlain(value, 'true');
     target[ key ] = $.isPlainObject( target[ key ] ) ?
      $.widget.extend( {}, target[ key ], value ) :

      // Don't extend strings, arrays, etc. with objects
      $.widget.extend( {}, value );

    // Copy everything else by reference
    } else {
          logPlain(value, 'false');
     target[ key ] = value;
    }
   }
  }
 }
 return target;
};

$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.widget2", {
    options: {
      data: null
    },
    _create: function() {
      var isDataEqual = this.options.data == data.colors;
      $('#equal').text(isDataEqual ? "true" : "false");
    },
  });

  $("#my-widget1").widget2({
    data: data.colors
  });

});
```

```css
#equal, #plain {
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.31);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="my-widget1">Testing 'nodeType' in jQuery version-3.1.1</div>
  <div>isPlainObject: <span id="plain"></div>
  <div>isDataEqual: <span id="equal"></span></div>
</div>
```

Call stack when creating new jQuery UI widget:

- _createWidget(options)
- $.widget.extend({}, options)
- $.isPlainObject(options.colors)

If `$.isPlainObject(options.colors) == true` then `options.colors` is cloned into a new object `options` (jQuery 3.1.1). `isDataEqual` will be false.

Otherwise `options.colors` is copied by reference to a new object `options` (jQuery 1.11.0). `isDataEqual` will be true.

Why? In jQuery 1.11.2 in the method `$.isPlainObject` there is the following check:

```
if ( !obj || jQuery.type(obj) !== "object" || obj.nodeType || jQuery.isWindow( obj ) ) {
    return false;
}
```

So if there is a property `nodeType` in the object, the method `$.isPlainObject` returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your difference in comparison when I compare both versions of jquery I found the difference in isPlainObject method of jquery. If you replace your 3.x isPlainObject method from 1.x isPlainObject method you will get same result as 1.x

please find screenshot for comparison.

[image]