# JSONModel Compare Models with each other

Tags: sapui5, jsonmodel

I only want save the data of a Model if something of the properties has changed.
Therefore I would like to compare the original and the "changed" properties with each other.
Found this hint by Sergio, but without a sample.
https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3667904

Would be nice if someone of you could help me with a nice solution.

Thanks,
Dirk

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "save" in "I only want to save the data of a model"? What are you trying to achieve or avoid?

Comment: Hi Boghyou, I only want send requests to the backend if it has changed.

Comment: Is your data actually coming from an OData protocol?

Comment: @boghyon: no, ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using JSONModels, extract each model's data using the getJSON method and then transform them into JS objects.

```
var oModelA = this.getView().getModel("modelName");
var oModelB = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
    a: 2
});
var oModelAData = JSON.parse(oModelA.getJSON());
var oModelBData = JSON.parse(oModelB.getJSON());
```

then, compare them using any way avaiable here that suits you

[How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

[jQuery object equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176962/jquery-object-equality)

Comment: var oModelErstellerOriginalData = JSON.parse(oModelErstellerOriginal.getJSON());
   var oModelErstellerData   = JSON.parse(oModelErsteller.getJSON());

Comment: My issue is still that there is still a reference to the changed Model. Within of the oModelErstellerOriginalData the values do have changed too. How can I avoid this reference to the changed Model?

Comment: `var oModelErstellerOriginalData = JSON.parse(oModelErstellerOriginal.getJSON());
     this.oModelErstellerOriginal = _.clone(oModelErstellerOriginalData);`

Comment: Got it to work with Lodash (Removed the reference). Thanks for your help

Comment: `this.oModelErstellerOriginal;
var oModelErstellerData = JSON.parse(oModelErsteller.getJSON());
if (_.isEqual(oModelErstellerData, this.oModelErstellerOriginal)){` For comparing of this two objects I used Lodash too.